# empty list in kmeans implementation using python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm writing a K-Means cluster for a project which uses clusters to identify objects, so the robot is freely almost autonomous. The camera basically captures a picture in a half second
rate, which is stores in a 'blob' of pixels. This blob is sent to the data mining algorithm, k-means, which identify the 'shades' of the object as a cluster, so the robot can be programmed to avoid those areas. I post my k-means code. it's written in python.

```
import sys, math, random

class Point:

    def __init__(self, coords, reference=None):
        self.coords     = coords
        self.n          = len(coords)
        self.reference  = reference

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.coords)

class Cluster:

    def __init__(self, points):

        if len(points) == 0: 
            raise Exception("ILLEGAL: empty cluster")

        self.points = points
        self.n      = points[0].n       # make the first element to be the number of clusters

        for p in points:
            if p.n != self.n:
                raise Exception("ILLEGAL: wrong dimension")

        self.centroid = self.calculateCentroid()

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.points)

    def update(self, points):
        old_centroid    = self.centroid
        self.points     = points
        self.centroid   = self.calculateCentroid()
        return getDistance(old_centroid, self.centroid)

    def calculateCentroid(self):
        reduce_coord = lambda i:reduce(lambda x,p : x + p.coords[i], self.points, 0.0)
        if len(self.points) == 0:
            print "Dividing by 0"
            self.points = [1]
        centroid_coords = [reduce_coord(i) / len(self.points) for i in range(self.n)]

        return Point(centroid_coords)

def kmeans(points, k, cutoff):

    initial = random.sample(points, k)
    clusters = [Cluster([p]) for p in initial]
    print clusters
    while True:
        lists = [ [] for c in clusters]
        for p in points:
            smallest_distance   = getDistance(p, clusters[0].centroid)
            index = 0

            for i in range(len(clusters[1:])):
                distance = getDistance(p, clusters[i+1].centroid)
                if distance < smallest_distance:

                    smallest_distance = distance
                    index = i+1

                lists[index].append(p)
            biggest_shift = 0.0

            for i in range(len(clusters)):
                shift = clusters[i].update(lists[i])
                biggest_shift = max(biggest_shift, shift)

            if biggest_shift < cutoff:
                break

    return clusters

def getDistance(a, b):

    if a.n != b.n:
        raise Exception("ILLEGAL: non comparable points")

    ret = reduce(lambda x, y: x + pow((a.coords[y] - b.coords[y]), 2), range(a.n), 0.0)
    return math.sqrt(ret)

def makeRandomPoint(n, lower, upper):
    return Point([random.uniform(lower, upper) for i in range(n)])

def main():
    num_points, dim, k, cutoff, lower, upper = 10, 2, 3, 0.5, 0, 200
    points = map(lambda i: makeRandomPoint(dim, lower, upper), range(num_points))

    clusters = kmeans(points, k, cutoff)

    for i, c in enumerate(clusters):
        for p in c.points:
            print "Cluster: ", i, "\t Point: ", p


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sure enough, it's not working!

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\philippe\Documents\workspace-sts-2.7.2.RELEASE\scribber\kmeans\kmeans.py", line 100, in ?
    main()    
  File "C:\Users\philippe\Documents\workspace-sts-2.7.2.RELEASE\scribber\kmeans\kmeans.py", line 92, in main
[    clusters = kmeans(points, k, cutoff)
[[89.152748179548524, 81.217634455465131]], [[83.439023369838509, 169.75355953688432]], [[1.8622622156419633, 41.364078271733739]]]
Dividing by 0
  File "C:\Users\philippe\Documents\workspace-sts-2.7.2.RELEASE\scribber\kmeans\kmeans.py", line 69, in kmeans
    shift = clusters[i].update(lists[i])
  File "C:\Users\philippe\Documents\workspace-sts-2.7.2.RELEASE\scribber\kmeans\kmeans.py", line 35, in update
    self.centroid   = self.calculateCentroid()
  File "C:\Users\philippe\Documents\workspace-sts-2.7.2.RELEASE\scribber\kmeans\kmeans.py", line 43, in calculateCentroid
    centroid_coords = [reduce_coord(i) / len(self.points) for i in range(self.n)]
  File "C:\Users\philippe\Documents\workspace-sts-2.7.2.RELEASE\scribber\kmeans\kmeans.py", line 39, in <lambda>
    reduce_coord = lambda i:reduce(lambda x,p : x + p.coords[i], self.points, 0.0)
  File "C:\Users\philippe\Documents\workspace-sts-2.7.2.RELEASE\scribber\kmeans\kmeans.py", line 39, in <lambda>
    reduce_coord = lambda i:reduce(lambda x,p : x + p.coords[i], self.points, 0.0)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'coords'
```

When I do a print in `lists` in the function `kmeans(points, k, cutoff)` I get
`[[], [], []]`. I'm trying to figure it out, why is that returning me an empty list. I posted the entire code, so one can run the code and replicate the error. In the error log, it's possible to see what 'clusters` is: that list of points.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if the list of points closest to a given cluster is empty (all the points are closer to a different cluster), then you'll get a divide by 0 error, at which point you assign garbage data to self.points which causes the eventual error you are seeing.

This is possible if two clusters have the same centroid, in which case the second cluster will never have points assigned to it.

Incidentally, there's another bug. You have an extra indent in front of 
    lists[index].append(p)
You should consider rewriting that whole loop using enumerate and min to make it cleaner anyway.

Here's how I'd suggest rewriting things.

```
while True:
    newPoints = dict([(c,[]) for c in clusters])
    for p in points:
        cluster = min(clusters, key = lambda c:getDistance(p, c.centroid))
        newPoints[cluster].append(p)

    biggest_shift = 0.0

    for c in clusters:
        if newPoints[c]:
            shift = c.update(newPoints[c])
            biggest_shift = max(biggest_shift, shift)

    if biggest_shift < cutoff:
        break
```

Comment: `lists` is empty: when I did a print in `lists = [ [] for c in clusters]` it returned me `[[],[],[]]`. So how can I make your changes (i.e `newPoints = collections.defaultdict(list)`)?

Comment: Where are you printing it? Anyway, as I pointed out you have indentation problems in the code you posted.

Comment: inside the 'while True: lists = [ [] for c in clusters] print lists`

Comment: The indentation problems is probably due stackoverflow. I don't have that indentation problem in my eclipse.

Comment: Also, the software is written in python 2.4, so `collections.defaultdict` can't be used

Comment: If you print the lists immediately after creating them, of course they're going to be empty! You need to print them after you're done adding the points to them. Also, I changed it so it doesn't use defaultdict.